Why is _site_sitename Appearing in Canonical URLs in Sitecore Experience Edge and How to Fix It?
I’m encountering an issue where _site_sitename is being appended to the canonical URLs generated for my pages in Sitecore XM Cloud Preview using Sitecore Experience Edge.
Actual URL :
https://www.mysite.com/_site_sitename/page-name

Expected URL :
https://www.mysite.com/page-name

any help how can i remove this site_sitename form canonical URL's

I have this utility function that I use instead of usePathname.  Unlike the other answers, this will account for all middleware rewrites (that are properly formed) because it's the same logic that is used to call the layout service.
import { pathExtractor } from 'lib/extract-path';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

/**
 * The path name on the server includes our rewritten path, which is different from on the client
 * This causes a hydration error.  Use the pathExtractor to get the real path.
 * @returns
 */
export function useRealPathName() {
  const pathName = usePathname();
  const path = pathExtractor.extract({ path: pathName });
  return path;
}


I can help you partway, which is to get relative URLs stripping out the _site_sitename bit. Getting the domain name has proven tricky, but if someone has that portion, I'd love to see it.
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
export const Default = (props: MetadataProps): JSX.Element => {
  const path = usePathname();
  canonicalUrl = path.replace(/^\/_[^/]+/, '');
  return (
    <Head>
      <title>{htmlTitle}</title>
      <link rel="canonical" href={canonicalUrl} />
    </Head>
  );
}


To remove the site rewrite data, you should use the normalizeSiteRewrite(pathname: string) function from the Sitecore JSS SDK site utils: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/5ff3d0a62c5beb343b1192d9492836fe50a22af4/packages/sitecore-jss/src/site/utils.ts#L45
This function works with both relative and absolute URLs.
